# Use access token instead of username and password to log in an account?

Tags: android

As part of my app I want to give the user an option to get into his Google account without entering a username and a password.

Is there a way I can use the Android "account manager" for that?

I know there's a way to get an access token, can I use it instead of username+password to log in?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I never used the Android AccountManager, but maybe [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) will help you

Comment: walked through this doc but couldn't find any answer. thanks anyway Kraxi